# Moving an object to the right margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I need a macro that aligns an object against the right margin, on the current line if this leaves a space between the text and the object, and on the next line otherwise. No other material should appear on the same line as the object in the latter case.

[image: Right alignment illustration]

My first attempt (`\tmarksi`) seems to work, but it causes underfull hbox warnings if it occurs at the end of a paragraph (I don't understand why). The second attempt (`\tmarksii`) seems to insert an unwanted paragraph break. Therefore I tried locally setting `\parskip` to zero in the third attempt, but this doesn't work either.

Surely this should not be difficult; what am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{2cm} %For illustration purposes
%
\newcommand\tmarksi[1]{\hspace*{\fill}~\mbox{[#1]}\newline}
\newcommand\tmarksii[1]{\hspace*{\fill}~\mbox{[#1]}\vskip0pt}
\newcommand\tmarksiii[1]{\hspace*{\fill}~\mbox{[#1]}\bgroup\parskip=0pt\parindent=0pt\par\egroup}
%
\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. \tmarksi{1}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over \tmarksi{1}
the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner --- Done.

Comment: I'm not getting any `Overfull \hbox warnings` with `\tmarksi` and that approach seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Werner --- You need to insert a blank line after a `\tmarksi`. I'll edit the question later; I don't have time now.

Comment: @Werner --- edited.

Comment: @Frank --- edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a variant of the "Bourbaki problem" in the TeXbook

```
\documentclass[convert,border=2]{standalone}

\newcommand{\tmark}[1]{%
  {{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \hskip2em\vadjust{}\nobreak\hfil[#1]%
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par
  \penalty 10000 \parskip=0pt\noindent}}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{150pt}\parindent=20pt\parskip=20pt
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\tmark{1}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over\tmark{1}
the lazy dog.

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy \tmark{1}
the lazy dog.

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog \tmark{1}

Another
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

This introduces a paragraph break, but also issues `\noindent` and `\penalty 10000` that inhibits a page break. I've added also `\parskip=0pt` to cover our tracks. The minimum space between the end of text and the mark is 2em, play with it.

Note: the `\parskip` is set in the `minipage` just to show the effect. Also `\parindent` needs to be set, otherwise it's zero.

[image]

To get the text flush right in case the mark is moved to the next line, change the first `\hfil` into `\hskip0pt`. For a normal interword space as the minimum, change `\hskip2em` into `\space`.

The following version implements this and also avoids page breaks in case the mark is moved to the next line:

```
\newcommand{\tmark}[1]{%
  {{\unskip\nobreak\vadjust{\nobreak}\hskip0pt\penalty50 \space
  \vadjust{}\nobreak\hfil[#1]%
  \clubpenalty=0 \widowpenalty=0 \brokenpenalty=0
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par
  \penalty 10000 \parskip=0pt\noindent}}\ignorespaces}
```

There is a price to pay: we have less control of widow and club lines, but as Frank Mittelbach remarks in the comments it seems quite hard to comply with both necessities.

Comment: So if I want a normal interword space it should be `\hskip\fontdimen2\font minus \fontdimen4\font`, right?

Comment: @IanThompson And `plus \fontdimen3\font`.

Comment: Would that make any difference when there is a `\hfil` to the left?

Comment: @IanThompson With `\hfil` instead of a non zero `\hskip` the space before the mark could well be zero.

Comment: I mean the `plus \fontdimem3\font`.

Comment: @IanThompson I don't understand what `\hfil` you're talking about. You can omit the stretch component, if you want, but that space will not participate to the stretching on the line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2210/discussion-between-ian-thompson-and-egreg)

Comment: @egrep The disadvantage with this approach is that it adds a `\widowpenalty` in the line before fake `\par`. And you can't really cancel that either since you may in fact be on the last real line.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Adding `\widowpenalty=0` should cure the problem (the setting is local as that of `\parfillskip`). It depends mostly on the real application the OP has in mind what's the best approach.

Comment: @egrep It wouldn't because the widowpenalty may be correct in this place. What I'm saying is you don't know, which is why you can't fix it. Which is why I suggest sticking with a single real paragraph (either two different commands or a penalty like 9999). But otherwise the solution with support for overlapping is clearly the nicer one.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach Right. However there's a bigger problem with both solutions: if the mark is moved to the next line, it may be detached by a page break.

Comment: Some manual tweaking of page breaks is always necessary in the documents in which this command is used. Moreover, I have to stick to an existing interface, so I can't define two different commands. Therefore egreg's solution wins the day.

Answer (score 11):

I assume you meant that `\tmarksi` generates an underfull hbox not an overfull one if it comes at the end of the paragraph. The reason for this behavior is that the `\newline` in that definition always starts another line in that paragraph and then the final line is fully empty. This is why in LaTeX `\\` or `\newline` are introduced as line separators not as line endings (though many people try to use `\\ \\` to get empty lines or extra space).

So, this means either you write two different commands for the two cases or you try something like this:

```
\newcommand\tmarksi[1]{\hspace*{\fill}~\mbox{[#1]}\penalty -9999 }
```

What is different here is that I used a penalty which is not quite an "always break here" so that the final breakpoint at the end of the paragraph will overwrite it. However, within the paragraph it should normally be sufficient, that is as long as you do not use explicit `\linebreak` commands. So take your pick.

Comment: Any hints on doing this with `\discretionary`? It seems like you should be able to get TeX to pick the breakpoint for you, but I didnt have any luck.

Comment: @Justin I think you are mistaken. `\discretionary doesn't help you here. it can only consist of boxes characters and kerns (not flexible glue). What is needed is glue that pushes the mark to the right plus a breakpoint that ensures the line ends at this point. But the issue then is that a forced breakpoint just before `\par` will result result in an empty extra line. One could of course try to look ahead to see if par is coming but that again is not failsafe either if it is hidden deeply inside a following command or environment.

Comment: I'd add `\unskip\space` at the beginning of `\tmarksi`. Otherwise it's necessary to have a space before `\tmarksi`.