# Multiple line attribution at end of quote/verse environment

Tags: line-spacing, quoting, verse

I want to be able to write an attribution at the end of a quote/verse environment that spans multiple lines. I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203499/128068) which suggests this piece of code

```
\def\signed#1{{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
    \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\sl#1
    \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}}
```

I have adapted it by changing its name from `\signed` to `\attribute`, removing `\sl` and replacing it with `\small`.

I have tried using this `\attribute{...}` code on separate lines to achieve what I'm looking for. However, this requires me to manually reduce the vertical space between lines, I'm currently using `vspace{-0.15cm}`. This is an inelegant solution I know, is there a better way to do this? Ideally, I wouldn't have to use `\attribute{...}` on separate lines like this and could just write `\attribute{First line \\ Second line \\ Third Line}` and it would get all the spacing correct. (If there was a way I could specify the line spacing for the attribution using `\setstretch` that would be ideal)

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,inner=2.5cm,outer=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}

\def\attribute#1{{\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
    \hskip2em\hbox{}\nobreak\hfil\small #1
    \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0\par}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
%
\begin{verse} 
There is pleasure in the pathless woods,\\
There is rapture in the lonely shore, \\
There is society where none intrudes,\\
By the deep Sea, and music in its roar:\\
I love not Man the less, but Nature more.

\attribute{\textsc{Lord Byron}}
\vspace{-0.15cm}
\attribute{\textit{Childe Harold’s Pilgrimage}}
\vspace{-0.15cm}
\attribute{Canto IV, st. 178--186}
\end{verse}
%
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack it!

EDITED to change attribution size to `\small` and reduce the line spacing therein.  Also, made it part of `\attribute` macro.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,inner=2.5cm,outer=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\setstackgap{L}{11pt}
\setstretch{1.1}

\def\attribute#1{\hfill{\small\Longstack[r]{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
%
\begin{verse} 
There is pleasure in the pathless woods,\\
There is rapture in the lonely shore, \\
There is society where none intrudes,\\
By the deep Sea, and music in its roar:\\
I love not Man the less, but Nature more.

\attribute{
  \textsc{Lord Byron}\\
  \textit{Childe Harold’s Pilgrimage}\\
  Canto IV, st. 178--186}
\end{verse}
%
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there an easy way to make everything within this stack appear `\small`? Also, is there a way to control line spacing within it, using `\setstretch` perhaps?

Comment: @Milo Of course.  Done.  With the long stack, `\setstackgap{L}{...}` does the line spacing trick.

Comment: @milo I am a mind reader.  Did it before you asked.

Comment: @Milo So we are both mind readers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `flushright` combined with a `spacing` environment to specify the line spacing.  You will need to set `\topsep` to `0pt` and (perhaps) remove some vertical space afterwards:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,inner=2.5cm,outer=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}

\newenvironment{attribute}{%
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
  \begin{spacing}{0.9}%
    \begin{flushright}%
      \small}%
{\end{flushright}%
  \end{spacing}%
  \vspace{-\smallskipamount}%
}

\begin{document}
\showoutput
\blindtext
%
\begin{verse}
There is pleasure in the pathless woods,\\
There is rapture in the lonely shore, \\
There is society where none intrudes,\\
By the deep Sea, and music in its roar:\\
I love not Man the less, but Nature more.

\begin{attribute}
  \textsc{Lord Byron}\\
  \textit{Childe Harold’s Pilgrimage}\\
  Canto IV, st. 178--186
\end{attribute}
\end{verse}
%
\blindtext

\end{document}
```