# Line break causes right alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, line-breaking

I'm trying to display some text left aligned and right aligned with:

```
\bf{Left Aligned} \hfill Right aligned \hfil
```

But the right aligned section leaves a tab of empty whitespace before the end. If I use:

```
\bf{Left Aligned} \hfill Right aligned \hfil\break
```

The text is appropriately right aligned, but I don't want the extra break. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `\textbf{Left aligned}\hfill Right aligned}` and a blank line thereafter should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following mechanism will produce a one-line paragraph that starts flush left
and ends flush right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{\parindent=0pt \parfillskip=0pt
 \textbf{Left Aligned} \hfill Right aligned\par
}

\end{document}
```

if the paragraph is more than one line long, but the flush-right material
doesn't fit on what remains of the last line (although it is less than one
line long), then the mechanism used for a qed box on a theorem proof, or for
the signature on an epigraph, is more appropriate.  some possibilities are described here: [Moving an object to the right margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41071/579)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}
    \textbf{Left Aligned} \hfill Right aligned \hfil

    \textbf{Left Aligned} \hfill Right aligned \hfil\break

    \textbf{Left Aligned} \hfill Right aligned \hfill 

    \textbf{Left Aligned} \hfill Right aligned \hfill\break

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]