# hfill works different after syllabification

Tags: line-breaking, bugs

I realized that hfill only flushes the first word to the right if the line started with the second half of a syllabification. If there is a manual linebreak afterwards the problem does not occure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a very long sentence such that there has to be a point where a stu\-pendous line should be cut. \hfill test 123

This is a very long sentence such that there has to be a point where a stu\-pendous line should be cut. \hfill test 123\\

This is a very long sentence such that there has to be a point where this line should be cut. \hfill test 123
\end{document}
```

produces this:
[image]
This is a problem since I use hfill after quotes to give the author and date. Is there a reason for this behavior, is this a bug? I tested it with texlive 2017 and miktex 2.9.6300.

Comment: Using `\hfill` alone is not the best way for doing the job.

Comment: although the answer is a good one, since what is to be put at the end of the last line is only a few words, you can keep them together with ties `~` instead of spaces;  you'll still have a problem if the "final" phrase won't fit on the line.  some additional information here: [Line break causes right alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325843/579) and [Manual linebreak with justification but without empty line afterwards](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127644/579)

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in your input markup, you should be using `\hspace*{\fill}` to make a space that is not dropped at the start of a line. Unrelated to hyphenation, `\hfill` is dropped at the start of a line for the same reason that you do not get an inter-word space at the start of a line if tex inserts a linebreak, all discardable space is discarded after a line break. You may also want `test~123` to prevent a line break at that space. (It is hard to be sure what you want to happen in general)